# Enable Wordpress Plugin for a Custom Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a theme from scratch and I understand that you need to call a function to enable plugins. Right now, I want to add share buttons after every post and also in my sidebar.

I downloaded the plugin from here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-social-media-icons/

Obviously, it's not showing up when I activate it. What do I have to do to enable it on my custom theme?